# how to extract all objects from nested arrays into one array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

I have an array like this, which is the initial state of my `useState`:

```
Array [ (6) […], (6) […] ]
​
0: Array(6) [ undefined, {…}, {…}, … ]
​
1: Array(6) [ undefined, undefined, {…}, … ]
```

for example:

```
const[arr,setArr] = React.useState([
[
{label: "Beklam", id: 5032},
{label: "Dx6", id: 5052},
undefined,
undefined
],
[
{label: "item1", id: 50567},
{label: "item4", id: 505567},
{label: "item6", id: 50537},
{label: "itemA", id: 505647},
undefined,
undefined,
]
])
```

I want to make it like this:

```
[
{label: "Beklam", id: 5032},
{label: "Dx6", id: 5052},
{label: "item1", id: 50567},
{label: "item4", id: 505567},
{label: "item6", id: 50537},
{label: "itemA", id: 505647},
]
```

I should mention that `undefined` values came form inputs. in my case, it is possible to receive `undefined` and I should handle it.

this is from `console.log` output of browser. there's one array with two arrays inside of it. and each one of these 2 arrays have 6 elements inside of them. they can be more than 6. so the amount of elements are not static, as well as arrays.

the array can have multiple child arrays.

something like this:

```
0: undefined
1: undefined
2: Object { label: "Beklam", id: 5032 }
3: Object { label: "0/65%", id: 5061 }
4: undefined
5: undefined
```

I want to extract all objects inside of child arrays into one object. apparently extracting all values of those 2 arrays into a single array containing their objects.

and if possible, filtering `undefined`  values and not showing them. instead of trying to use `array.filter` later on variable.

I actually haven't encountered a problem like this. so I don't really know how can I handle multi dimensional arrays.

Comment: can you give me a dummy array instead some random characters `Array [ (6) […], (6) […] ]`?

Comment: in addition to providing a clearer example of your input, can you please clarify what your expected output should look like?

Comment: I think you want just `.flat()`?

Comment: @NickParsons now it is detailed. thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use flatmap to make it into one dimensional array.

```js
console.log(arr.flatMap((e) => e));
```

Or even simplier:

```js
console.log(arr.flat());
```

And to filter out the undefined values:

```js
console.log(arr.flatMap((e) => e.filter((f) => f !== undefined)));
```

Comment: This is equivalent to just `.flat()` since there is no mapping operation

Comment: Had never heard of flat, thanks ! (I'll edit this answer)

Comment: No worries, looks like OP changed their quesiton/input, looks like you might be better off using `.flatMap()` again considering the new input (with an inner `.filter()`)

Comment: Thank you so much Emilien and @NickParsons. I was looking for it for a long.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to get it flattened into a single array.

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove the `undefined` entries.

```js
const data = arr.flat(Infinity).filter(Boolean)
```

Comment: You can also use `.flat(Infinity)` if you want to flatten arbitrary depths

Comment: Indeed. Not sure why `Infinity` makes me nervous but it does.

Answer (score 0):

An another example using basic function of array like `filter()` and `concat()`:

```js
var arr = [
  [
    {label: "Beklam", id: 5032},
    {label: "Dx6", id: 5052},
    undefined,
    undefined
  ],
  [
    {label: "item1", id: 50567},
    {label: "item4", id: 505567},
    {label: "item6", id: 50537},
    {label: "itemA", id: 505647},
    undefined,
    undefined,
  ]
];
arr = arr[0].concat(arr[1]);
var arr2 = arr.filter(e => e != undefined && e);
console.log(arr2)
```